# playing audio in openTK

Tags: audio, openal, opentk

What's the easiest way to play audio (WAV, MP3, OGG, doesn't matter) in an OpenTK application?  I need to be able to play it, stop it, and get the current position in seconds at any time.  I've used WMPLib in my Forms apps in the past but that doesn't seem to work with OpenTK for whatever reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

OpenTK is just a graphics library, but [OpenAL](http://www.opentk.com/doc/audio) provides support for audio.

Comment: OpenTK is not just a graphics library. The front page of their website says "The Open Toolkit is an advanced, low-level C# library that wraps OpenGL, OpenCL and OpenAL.". Also, just knowing that OpenAL provides support for audio doesn't help knowing *how* to use it.